# How to override newsletter.phtml (my account option) in Magento 2

Tags: module, magento2.2, overrides, custom, newsletter

I would like to edit the "General Subscription" text in my custom theme present in the My Account page under the Newsletter Subscription menu.

I've already located the page which is:

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME_NAME/Magento_Customer/templates/form/newsletter.phtml
```

But I have no idea on ***how to create my custom module***.

***I've already created the registration.php and the module.php file.***

> ***but can you please explain me, what should I put in the layout folder? And also, what is the path of the templates folder? Just
>   templates/form/newsletter.phtml?***

Please, help me!

Thanks

Comment: Try using below way, it will definitely help you....     
https://meetanshi.com/blog/override-phtml-file-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: Only for the text change don't override the template file. Add text in translation file in your theme. (EX. app/design/frontend/Test/Base/i18n/en_US.csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the url like `baseurl/newsletter/manage`

so the xml file must be newsletter_manage_index.xml you can find this file from `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/layout/newsletter_manage_index.xml`

Override this file in you custom module

`app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/newsletter_manage_index.xml` with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Newsletter" name="customer_newsletter" cacheable="false" template="Vendor_Module::form/newsletter.phtml">
                <container name="customer.newsletter.form.before" as="form_before" label="Newsletter Subscription Form Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Default file's block doesn't have the template file path. It is declared in `Magento\Customer\Block\Newsletter.php` block file.

We have declared the custom phtml file path in xml as `Vendor_Module::form/newsletter.phtml`.

so copy the file from `Vendor/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/newsletter.phtml` to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/form/newsletter.phtml`

Comment: Thank you!! It worked like a charm :)

Comment: Np...please accept the answers if it is correct

Comment: Only for the text change don't override the template file. Add text in translation file in your theme. (EX. app/design/frontend/Test/Base/i18n/en_US.csv)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Override your Existing File so basically you need to follow such simple steps:

1. Create Module OSCP_NewsletterOveride - Path: app/code/OSCP/NewsletterOveride
2. Create module.xml file in path app/code/OSCP/NewsletterOveride/etc/module.xml

and paste this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="OSCP_NewsletterOveride" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

3. Create etc/registration.php file -path: app/code/OSCP/NewsletterOveride/registration.php

and paste this code

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'OSCP_NewsletterOveride',
    __DIR__
);
```

4. Now Enable the Module with command:`php bin/magento module:enable OSCP_NewsletterOveride`
5. This way you can create your Module.

**Now Override Newsletter File**

Create File `URL/newsletter/edit/`

Now Create **newsletter_edit_index.xml** in Path: `app/code/OSCP/NewsletterOveride/view/frontend/layout/newsletter_edit_index.xml`

and Add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Newsletter" name="customer_newsletter_form" template="OSCP_NewsletterOverride::form/newsletter.phtml">
                <container name="customer.newsletter.form" as="form_override" label="Newsletter Subscription" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="newsletter_form"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now copy your original newsletter file in following Path: `app/code/OSCP/NewsletterOveride/view/frontend/templates/form/newsletter.phtml`

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but with your xml file, it didn't override the previous one, but just added extra code to it.
In order to make it work, I had to replace the form_override with form_before as @Ranganathan suggested :)

Comment: Only for the text change don't override the template file. Add text in translation file in your theme. (EX. app/design/frontend/Test/Base/i18n/en_US.csv)